# How to get counter results in AppEngine MapReduce?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am using google [mapreduce lib](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/) to process my data. While processing the data, counter be used in the mapper function. But I don't know how to get the counter results in finalized method.

```
def mapper(obj):
    yield obj
    yield operation.counters.Increment("process-obj")


class Test(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    """A pipeline to ingest log as CSV in Google Storage
    """

    def run(self, setting_id):
        filepath = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            "test",
            "mapper",
            "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
            output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
            params={

            },
            shards=10
        )
    def finalized(self):
        # how to read the counter process-obj
        # how to get the setting_id
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named outputs is probably what you are looking for. You can find more details [here](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Named_outputs).

Here is your code using named outputs to get back the various counters including the one you defined:

```
def mapper(obj):
    yield obj
    yield operation.counters.Increment("process-obj")


class Test(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    """A pipeline to ingest log as CSV in Google Storage
    """

    output_names = ['counters']

    def run(self, setting_id):
        results = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
          "test",
          "mapper",
          "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
          output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
          params={

          },
          shards=10
        )
        yield MapreduceResult(results.counters)

    def finalized(self):
        print 'Counters here: ', self.outputs.counters


class MapreduceResult(base_handler.PipelineBase):

    def run(self, counters):
        self.fill(self.outputs.counters, counters)
```